# Custom View drawArc,detect user touch on draw path of arc

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am creating a custom view which is a kind of arc slider progress view.I can draw more or less of the arc based on where the user touches(on the x axis) by calculating the sweep, i do this by first calculating the percetage where the user touched along the x axis..0% would be all the way to the left and 100% would be all the way to the right.

I want to take this a step further, instead off drawing the arc based on the x coordinate that the user presses, I want to make it move only when the user touches on the actual arc draw path, so its more realistic. I am still new to custom views and my maths is limited but if I get some tips I would be grateful thanks

[image: how it looks when user moves there finger on the area of the rectangle as a percentage along the x axis]

```
class ArcProgress extends View {

    Context cx;
    float width;

    float height;
    float center_x, center_y;
    final RectF oval = new RectF();
    final RectF touchArea = new RectF();

    float sweep = 0;
    float left, right;
    int percent = 0;

    public ArcProgress(Context context) {
        super(context);
        cx = context;

    }

    public int getPercentage() {
        return percent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        setBackgroundColor(0xfff0ebde);

        width = (float) getWidth();
        height = (float) getHeight();

        float radius;

        if (width > height) {
            radius = height / 3;
        } else {
            radius = width / 3;
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(0xffd2c8b6);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(35);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        center_x = width / 2;
        center_y = height / 2;

        left = center_x - radius;
        float top = center_y - radius;
        right = center_x + radius;
        float bottom = center_y + radius;

        oval.set(left, top, right, bottom);

            //this is the background arc, it remains constant
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, 180, false, paint);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(0xffe0524d);
            //this is the red arc whichhas its sweep argument manipulated by on touch
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, sweep, false, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            float xPosition = event.getX();
            float yPosition = event.getY();
            if (oval.contains(xPosition, yPosition)) {

                float x = xPosition - left;
                float s = x * 100;
                float b = s / oval.width();
                percent = Math.round(b);
                sweep = (180 / 100.0f) * (float) percent;

                invalidate();

            } else {
                if (xPosition < left) {
                    percent = 0;

                    sweep = (180 / 100.0f) * (float) percent;
                    invalidate();
                }
                if (xPosition > right) {
                    percent = 100;

                    sweep = (180 / 100.0f) * (float) percent;
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this work for you?
You don't need a lot of Maths. You can calculate the distance of the touch point from the center of your arc (it's a circle so it's easy) and the compare that with the radius you are using. That will tell you if the point is on the arc (almost, see below for full case).

```
Point touchEv = ...; 
Point circleCenter = ...; 

//the radius of the circle you used to draw the arc
float circleRadius = ...; 
//how far from the arc should a touch point treated as it's on the arc
float maxDiff = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.max_diff_dp);

//calculate the distance of the touch point from the center of your circle
float dist = Math.pow(touchEv.x-circleCenter.x,2) + Math.pow(touchEv.y-  circleCenter.y,2)
dist = Math.sqrt(dist); 

//We also need the bounding rect of the top half of the circle (the visible arc)
Rect topBoundingRect = new Rect(circleCenter.x - circleRadius,
            circleCenter.y - circleRadius, 
            circleCenter.x + circleRadius,
            circleCenter.y);


if (Math.abs(dist - circleRadius)  <= maxDiff  &&
  topBoundingRect.contains(touchEv.x, touchEv.y)) {
  // the user is touching the arc 

}
```

Comment: i wish i ould choose 2 top answers, i will up click you thanks a million

Comment: i changed my mind and maked this correct since i still havnt fully got my head round it but your code works, are you on irc by any chance?

Comment: i wish i understood why it works. do you know any books I can read that focus on geometry that are geared towards developers?

Comment: hmmm, sorry I don't know any books for Maths for Devs. But what we are doing here is pretty simple, we are just comparing the distances from the center of the circle. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 12):

> I want to make it move only when the user touches on the actual arc
>   draw path

At the beginning of `onTouchEvent()` you need to check whether `xPosition` and `yPosition` are fulfilling some condition. If yes, you do the stuff, which you are doing now. If no, `return true`.

**Condition:**

We want to check whether x, y are in that grey arc background:

[image]

Let's calculate a distance from (x, y) to that point (a, b) in the center:

```
final dist = distance(x, y, a, b)
```

`distance()` is a simple Euclidean distance between points (x,y) and (a,b):

```
double distance(int x, int y, int a, int b)
{
    return Math.sqrt((x - a) * (x - a) + (y - b) * (y - b));
}
```

x, y are in that grey arc background, if `y > Y && dist >= r && dist <= R`.